# Static or Private

Tags: vb.net

This is one of those questions that has been niggling around in the back of my mind since day one of programming in VB in general. I have my own personal ideas about it, but I am wondering what the general consensus is on the use of static variables.

Static Variable:

```
Public Function Whatever() as Boolean
     Static Flag as Boolean
     If not Flag then
        ' do something
        Flag = True
     end if
     Return Something
End sub
```

VS:

Private Variable:

```
Private Flag as Boolean
Public Function Whatever() as Boolean
     If not Flag then
        ' do something
        Flag = True
     end if
     Return Something
End sub
```

Unless someone knows otherwise, the above are functionally equivalent, other than the fact that the "Private" Flag is exposed to be used elsewhere in the class.

Questions begin to arise with Statics.. like..

Where are they stored.. when are they REALLY created and disposed etc.

Obviously, the compiler adds them to the data heap (I know, bad usage of THAT word) for the class somehow... But is there a penalty for that in terms of overhead, garbage collection etc.

Generally I avoid them like the plague because they present more questions than answers.

Is there really any SOLID reason to ever use statics?

PS: Hopefully this passes the SO question test...

Note I am not asking specifics about how statics are created.. I am more asking what if ANYTHING would make using a static worth it.

**ADDENDUM....**

I did a little more research and found this rather enlightening.

https://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/7717

Comment: Variables declared static are commonly shared across all instances of a class... Also the static value of the variable is independent of the objects in which they are not unique for each object. I think of static as a constant in a way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a static variable in Visual Basic created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199698/when-is-a-static-variable-in-visual-basic-created)

Comment: Um... no @Zaggler statics are instance specific.

Comment: @Trevor so are you saying they are not commonly shared across instances of a class? What are you disagreeing with? Static variables are ***indeed shared between all class instances***.

Comment: Statics stay with the class instance . If I call the same function in another instance it has it's own copy of the static.

Comment: Kind of, all instances of the class will have see the same value of the property. but iif one instance change that it will reflect for all the other instances. In general they are shared between.

Comment: @Zaggler You have to distinguish between static *local* variables (which OP is talking about) and static non-local (instance level) variables. But either way, a static variable is *not* a constant, and shouldn’t be treated as one (though whether a non-local static variable should be mutable is another question, and another can of worms).

Comment: @KonradRudolph good point, my bad; it is Friday right? Also I didn't mean constant in that context, what I mean is it would reflect across all instances if it was changed...

Comment: MSDN: `When you declare a static variable in a Shared procedure, only one copy of the static variable is available for the whole application. ...When you declare a static variable in a procedure that isn't Shared, only one copy of the variable is available for each instance of the class. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from research I have come up with the following.

Static variables are "Lazy" variables, in that they are created when required the first time the function or routine is called. There is an overhead associated with the creation, and more importantly, first initialization in order to make it thread safe.

As Konrad suggests the main reason to use statics is to minimize the scope of the variable to where it is needed.

So... when required

1. Use SIMPLE static variables (Booleans, Integers etc.) in functions and subroutines that are less commonly used. If you expect the users of the class to ALWAYS call that function, and expect there to be 1,000s of instances of the class... you are adding A LOT of overhead.
2. Never use static variables of object types that need to be disposed unless you add some functionality (paramaters) to the routine that allow you to call it in a Dispose mode and remember to do so in the classes Dispose function.
3. Similarily, do not use a static variables as a reference to some other object in your project. Doing so can prevent said object from being garbage collected elsewhere in your code since it is still referenced.
4. Finally, if you use the Private variable method instead, give it a name that makes it obvious that the variable is being used for that function.. e.g. stat_Half_Time_Score

Answer (score 6):

> Is there really any SOLID reason to ever use statics?

Yes. It’s arguably in the first letter of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29): **S** for “single responsibility principle”. In this particular context it’s a slightly different rule:

> [Objects should have the smallest possible scope.](http://www.cpptips.com/cppconventions_63.html)

If an object isn’t needed outside scope *X*, it should be declared inside scope *X*. This ensures that it has a single responsibility, and isn’t improperly accessed elsewhere. It also ensures that only one method has the responsibility of accessing this object.

Hence, in your case, the best idea would indeed to make the variable a function-static (= local) variable rather than an object-private variable.

This is indeed fairly uncommon in my experience. But it is best practice.

(In terms of performance/memory these two variants would be exactly identical.)

Comment: Ah.. good to know the latter. Konrad. And yes I agree with that, however, there are limitations too, esp if you happen to use something more complex than a simple variable which would be out of scope of any disposal routine.